# Insert item into a sorted list with Julia (with and without duplicates)

Tags: sorting, insert, julia

**Main Question**: What is the fastest way to insert an item into a list that is already sorted using Julia?

Currently, I do this:

```
v = [1, 2, 3, 5] #example list
x = 4 #value to insert
index = searchsortedfirst(v, x) #find index at which to insert x
insert!(v, index, x) #insert x at index
```

**Bonus Question**: What if I want to simultaneously ensure no duplicates?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `searchsorted` to get the range of indices where the value occurs instead of just the first one and then use `splice!` to replace the values in that range with a new set of values:

```
insert_and_dedup!(v::Vector, x) = (splice!(v, searchsorted(v,x), [x]); v)
```

That's a nice little one-liner that does what you want.

```
julia> v = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5];

julia> insert_and_dedup!(v, 4)
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 3
 4
 5

julia> insert_and_dedup!(v, 3)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

This made me think that `splice!` should handle the case where the replacement is a single value rather than an array, so I may add that feature.

Comment: I've changed splice! to allow the replacement argument to be anything enumerable, which includes scalar values: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/e048f2bf1b8da56b07738c0a4d142cd29e140e98. You can now define `insert_and_dedup!(v::Vector, x) = (splice!(v, searchsorted(v,x), x); v)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks also for all your work on julia. I'm loving the language.

Comment: i tried this in julia 1.6.1 and it doesn't dedup anymore, but inserts the value in the correct place

Answer (score 0):

For sorted arrays of structs a modified version of StefanKarpinski solution would look like the example below:

```
struct TimeEvent
    date::Dates.DateTime
    type::String
end
    
v = [
    TimeEvent(DateTime("2019-03-01"),"data_release") 
    TimeEvent(DateTime("2019-02-01"),"data_release") 
    TimeEvent(DateTime("2019-05-01"),"data_release") 
 ]

new_event=TimeEvent(DateTime("2019-04-01"),"data_release") 

# Sort Events
sort!(v, by = v -> v.date, rev=true) 

# Define Function
sortedStructInsert!(v::Vector, x) = (splice!(v, 
    searchsorted(v,x,by= v->v.date, rev=true), [x]); v)

# Call function
sortedStructInsert!(v, new_event)
```

```
4-element Vector{TimeEvent}:
 TimeEvent(DateTime("2019-05-01T00:00:00"), "data_release")
 TimeEvent(DateTime("2019-04-01T00:00:00"), "data_release")
 TimeEvent(DateTime("2019-03-01T00:00:00"), "data_release")
 TimeEvent(DateTime("2019-02-01T00:00:00"), "data_release")
```

The example below allows you to specify which field of the struct is the one that sorts, for a more generic implementation.

```
sortedStructInsert!(v::Vector, x,symbol) = (splice!(v,
    searchsorted(v,x,by= v->getproperty(v,symbol), rev=true), [x]); v)
sortedStructInsert!(v, new_event, :date)
```